# Xna-vectors and simulation of physical

Tags: xna

Is it possible to use the xna Vector for physical simulation of the aircraft 
If Yes ... How represent force and its destination?
(start point, end point....etc)

Where can I find help in for simulate the physics of the aircraft?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

XNA's Vector2, Vector3, and Vector4 class are just standard vector structures like any traditional game engine uses. Your question is basically asking "How do vectors work to represent physics properties?", which is an extremely broad question that would take pages to explain, I recommend revising your question to something more specific, backed by some effort and research on your part.

Here's an extremely simple answer since the full answer would be too big:
1.) Vectors can represent position.

```
(0, 1.5, 3)  // Represents a position of 0 along X-axis, 1.5 along Y, and 3.0 along Z.
```

2.) Vectors can represent linear velocity, generally in units per second.

```
(0, 1.5, 3)  
// Represents a linear velocity that covers a distance of 0 units along X-axis,
// 1.5 units along Y, and 3.0 units along Z, per second.
```

3.) Vectors can represent angular velocity, generally in radians per second around each axis, and generally they are axes local to the object, not world axes.

```
(0, 1.5, 3)  
// Represents an angular velocity that rotates the object by 0 radians around the object's local X-axis, 1.5 radians around the Y, and 3.0 radians around the Z, per second.
```

4.) Vectors can represent directions, generally unit-length directions. Directions can be multiplied by speeds to create linear or angular velocities, or can be used finding angles between other direction vectors, or can be used to find cross-products. Directions can also represent surface normals for things like calculating slopes for AI, or for physical deflections off of a surface, and much more.

```
(0.707, 0, 0.707)  // Represents a direction that points from (0, 0, 0) to (.707, 0. .707).
```

All of the properties of vectors are unrelated to any one game engine, they're just mathematics. XNA has a full-featured Vector class that makes a lot of things easier than if you had to write one yourself. If you're interested in what a Vector class looks like though, [here's an example](http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-vector-mathematics-complete.html).